# React, refetch from api when item is added

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have 3 components:

1. Tree
2. TreeView
3. TreeNode

in Tree - I fetch data from the api thru UseEffect and send it to TreeView
in TreeView - I recursively build a tree based on the data in jsx and send each item to TreeNode
in TreeNode - I can edit the node and send http request to change it

the problem is, the changes won't display until I refresh the page.
is there any way I can call a parent to re-render its child components after a successful edit without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass to the children the fetch function of the data. There is an example

```
const Tree = props => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(defaultState);

  const fetchData = () => {
    fakeApiFetch().then(data => setItems(data));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <TreeView>
      {items.map(item => (
        <TreeNode {...item} key={item.id} fetchData={fetchData}>
          //update item => then call props.fetchData
        </TreeNode>
      ))}
    </TreeView>
  );
};
```